# Change div contents on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a web page to change a divs `#portfolioWork` content upon clicking a link, I have tried a script that has been previously posted on here, however no such luck, even after switching around the id's to be called.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
$('#GFXWork').click(function(){
    $('#portfolioWork').load('portfolioContent.html #motionGraphics');
}
</script>


<nav id="portfolioNav">
<ul>
<li id="portfolio-compositing"><a href="#">Compositing</a></li>
<li id="portfolio-animation"><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
<li id="portfolio-motionGfx"><a id="GFXWork" href="#">Motion Graphics</a></li>
<li id="portfolio-3D"><a href="#">3D</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="portfolioWork">

<div id='Portfolio3D'>
<a class="fancyYoutube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rATNlIvsOWk">
<figcaption id="BikeRender">
<div class="captiontitle">3D Ident to Music</div>
<p class="maincaption">Apply attractive visuals to a short soundtrack to create an ident. Explore 3D particle systems and other simulation techniques to work towards the final outcome.</p>
<p class="captionFooter">Autodesk Maya and Adobe Photoshop were used.</p>
</figcaption>
<img src="Images/ident2Small.png"/></a>

<a class="fancyYoutube" href="Images/3DBikeLarge.png">
<figcaption id="BikeRender">
<div class="captiontitle">Rendering Techniques</div>
<p class="maincaption">Use reference materials to accurately texture a 3D bicycle model and light it to products standards. Composite the render outcomes to achieve quality images.</p>
<p class="captionFooter">Autodesk Maya and Adobe Photoshop were used.</p>
</figcaption>
<img src="Images/3DBikeSmall.png"/></a>

<a class="fancyChurch" rel="churchPoster" href="Images/PosterChurchLarge.png">
<figcaption id="ChurchRender">
<div class="captiontitle">Realistic Modelling</div>
<p class="maincaption">Gather reference materials in order to create a full 3D replica of a local building. Using a wide range of modelling techniques, add lights, textures and shaders for a complete effect.</p>
<p class="captionFooterChurch">Autodesk Maya and Adobe Photoshop were used.</p>
</figcaption>
<img src="Images/3DChurchSmall.png"/>
<a class="fancyChurch2" rel="churchPoster" href="Images/PosterChurch_AO.png">
</a>
</div> <!-- End of 3DWork -->
</div> <!-- End of PortfolioWork
```

I should be linking to a html file called portfolioContent.html which is located in the root folder alongside the portfolio.html page.

portfolioContent.html:

```
<div id="motionGraphics">
<a class="fancyYoutube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rATNlIvsOWk">
<figcaption id="BikeRender">
<div class="captiontitle">3D Ident to Music</div>
</figcaption>
<img src="Images/ident2Small.png"/></a>

<a class="fancyYoutube" href="Images/3DBikeLarge.png">
<figcaption id="BikeRender">
<div class="captiontitle">Rendering Techniques</div>
<p>BLAAAAAAAAAAAH</p>
</figcaption>
<img src="Images/3DBikeSmall.png"/></a>

<a class="fancyChurch" rel="churchPoster" href="Images/PosterChurchLarge.png">
<figcaption id="ChurchRender">
<div class="captiontitle">Realistic Modelling</div>
<p class="maincaption">Gather reference materials in order to create a full 3D replica of a local building. Using a wide range of modelling techniques, add lights, textures and shaders for a complete effect.</p>
<p class="captionFooterChurch">Autodesk Maya and Adobe Photoshop were used.</p>
</figcaption>
<img src="Images/3DChurchSmall.png"/>
<a class="fancyChurch2" rel="churchPoster" href="Images/PosterChurch_AO.png">
</a>
</div> <!-- End of motionGraphcs -->
```

Any such help would be greatly appreciated as I'm now completely lost as to what the issue may be!

Comment: Move your script to the bottom of the page, or at least after #GFXWork is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code inside DOM ready: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#GFXWork').click(function(){
        $('#portfolioWork').load('portfolioContent.html #motionGraphics');
    });

});
</script>
```

Since you use old version of JQuery, use this code for fancybox:

```
$('.fancyYoutube').live('click',function(){

$.fancybox({
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
'width' : 680,
'height' : 395,
'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
'type' : 'swf',
'swf' : {
'wmode' : 'transparent',
'allowfullscreen' : true
}
});
return false;
});
$("a[rel=churchPoster]").fancybox({
        'interval'          :  2500,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
        'showNavArrows'     : 'true',  
        'width'             :  680,
        'height'            :  395
    });
```

However, live() is deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/live/, maybe you could update JQuery, and use on() - rather. As i can see they recommend delegate() method for older versions... However, this will work. :)

Comment: This is perfect, however there is now an issue. When i switch the div content, the fancybox no longer works on the thumbnails and links directly to the image/video.

Fancybox is only working on the original content, as soon as i switch it, none of the thumbnails make use of it

Comment: @MattMeadows - i can't see where you include fancybox script? Link to test pages/site would be fine.

Comment: http://www.mattmeadows.info/JessWebsite/portfolio.html

Should you require any additional, please let me know.

Thankyou for your help so far!

Edit: Just as a pointer, only 'Motion Graphics' and '3D' have finished contents, but it should give you an idea of the issue within '3D'

Comment: Yes, well known problem with ajax loaded content (which is not in DOM when page is loaded). Please see updated answer. :)

Comment: Absolutely spot on!
I'll take a look into updating JQuery, you're right, i should be using the latest!
One more question, if I have a look around for JQuery transitions, am i correct that i could add a simple transition to the div content change? Like a slide in or fade as such?

Comment: EDIT: There appears to be the same issue with the image gallery, the thumbnail titled "Realistic Modelling" within '3D'
I suspect it is the same issue, however the JS for fancybox is `$("a[rel=churchPoster]").fancybox({` with no option to add live()

Comment: As long as it suit your needs, you don't have to change it, and don't forget to use on() method - ajax loaded content will not work without it...yes you can set fadeIn, but then you must change css properties of portfoliowork div... p.s. about last image/link... you can make separate call to fancybox...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PJhLv/ I have tried to call fancybox separately for the image gallery/link however it still links/display the image not within fancybox. Am i missing something?

Comment: It now works as far as loading fancybox, however a message is displayed "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."

Comment: @MattMeadows, please see new answer, problem is solved. :) This question haunted, me, LOL. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can Also use

```
$(function(){
    $('#GFXWork').click(function(){
        $('#portfolioWork').append('Place your code here');
    });
});
```

But your have to escape `"` characters with `\` not to be mixed with javascript `"`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding manual call to image, after checking fancybox manual call examples (sometimes, carefull reading of manual/documentation is good thing:)), here is solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// in your case $(".fancyChurch").live('click',function() {

    $("#fancyChurch").live('click',function() {

        $.fancybox({
            'interval'          :  2500,
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
            'showNavArrows'     : 'true',  
            'width'             :  680,
            'height'            :  395,
            'href'              : 'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg' //path to your church image


        });    
        return false;
    });
});
```

so, when you call image 'manually', as they say - href option should be provided. :)

Comment: Thankyou for all your help so far!
However, it now links directly to the image to display it again, instead of displaying it within fancybox :(

Comment: Add 'id=fancyChurch' to link, must work, i have used id, for testing, and you use class, right? Or, replace '#' with '.'. :)

Comment: Have changed `#fancychurch` in the JS to `.fancychurch` as it do indeed use classes. 
It now loads the lightbox again, but same message appears as before. The image gallery originally used rel="churchPoster" to display the images, as fancybox requires both/all images to be displayed to be within the same rel=

Comment: http://Images/PosterChurchLarge.png should be: "http://www.mattmeadows.info/JessWebsite/Images/PosterChurchLarge.png" FULL PATH to your image - if all is properly, set -. this must work. :) So, fix it in your code -> in manual call to image. full path starts with http... etc etc...

Comment: You're right! It needed a direct, full link to the image! Although, it doesn't transition to the second image? Does that require href'ing too?